# Ace editor not processing '&'

Tags: php, jquery, ace-editor

I'm having a problem with my own online code editor(I'm using Ace editor). It's working fine but it has one problem when it is saving code.

If a file contains a `&` somewhere, it will delete that character end all of the code after it.

Now I first thought it was the problem of my PHP code but I know now that it isn't. If I only input a `&` as code it will return me the error that there has not been any code submitted...

As an example, the code before I submitted it:

[image]

The code after I've submitted it:

[image]

I've not got many experience with Ace editor so that's why I'm asking my question here. Hope you guys can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to HTML or URL encode those values, depending on how you can submitting them to the server

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Via HTML/Javascript the code is going to an other PHP file and the PHP file is submitting it trough the server. I'm gonna lookup the encoding part.

Comment: Try using `encodeURIComponent`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Wow! Thank you very much! If you can give the answer than I will aprove it :-)

Comment: Glad to help. I've added my answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` character (amongst others) in the in editor value needs to be encoded when it is sent to the server. You can do this by using `encodeURIComponent`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent